# How do I fake-time a jQuery animation using Sinon in a Jasmine unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jquery-animate, jasmine, sinon

I have a 1 second jQuery `.animate` action that launches 5 seconds after page load. I set up a Sinon timer in my Jasmine unit testing code and test after a tick of 7 seconds to see if the post-animation properties are as they should be.

It doesn't work right, so I've placed an instance of the animation itself on my Jasmine HTML test page to better see what's going on.

- In Firefox and Chrome, the page loads, the animation function is called, the unit test immediately fails, and then (also immediately) the animation visibly occurs.
- In IE, Opera and Safari, the page loads, the animation function is called, the unit test immediately fails, and the animation never visibly occurs.

What I hoped for was the following (in all browsers):

- The page loads, the animation function is called, the animation completes instantaneously, and the unit test immediately succeeds.

Looking at [Sinon's documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock), it's fake timers cover the following processes:
`setTimeout`, `clearTimeout`, `setInterval`, `clearInterval`, `Date`

I don't know how jQuery's animation works, but I imagine it is using CSS to transition, and CSS transitions are not covered in Sinon's `useFakeTimers`, so I imagine this is the problem. However, if I'm right about the problem I still need a solution.

Maybe I should try something other than Sinon? Jasmine's `waits()` works perfectly in this test, but is incredibly impractical for impatient folks like myself.

Any other suggestions? Please keep in mind that I am new to JS unit testing, so vague answers will confuse me more than help me.  ;o)

Comment: It's been a couple of days and no one has answered. What I am doing right now, to resolve this, is using Jasmine's waits() functionality. It has worked well, although the tests are not instantaneous but rather are completed in real-time. Shucks. Please do post any other ideas you may have for me. Thanks.

Comment: hey! did you find any new solution to this problem? The $.fx.off answer works perfectly, but it still is not the way it should be...

Comment: I did not. I've been using waits(). I'd actually forgotten all about this question. But seeing as Derek's solution is simpler than Alex's and it has several votes in its favor (thus it probably works for others), I will try it out and mark it as the answer if it works for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [jQuery off](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/) to turn off jQuery effects:

```
jQuery.fx.off = true
```

This won't solve your problem of the inital 7 second wait for your event to fire but it does mean you can test that the DOM has been changed as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem. I believe it happens because jQuery's animation takes advantage of `requestAnimationFrame()` if it's available instead relying of the `setTimeout()`.

I've worked around this issue by setting all browser-specific `requestAnimationFrame` functions on the `window` object to null:

```
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame = null;
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame = null;
window.oRequestAnimationFrame = null;
```

Make sure this code executes *before* jQuery is loaded.

Comment: This didn't work for me when using jasmine + jquery + sinon.js. I even made sure it loaded as a src dependency before any of my spec files or even jquery. Maybe I did something wrong? Strange thing is, when I run the test alone (without any others), it passes.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible with SinonJs as it showed here: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-timers/

```
test("should animate element over 500ms", function () {
   var el = jQuery("<div></div>");
   el.appendTo(document.body);

   el.animate({ height: "200px", width: "200px" });
   this.clock.tick(510);

   equals("200px", el.css("height"));
   equals("200px", el.css("width"));
});
```