# How do you turn off a jquery animation timer in an angular unit test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am testing a directive that removes an element from the page after it fadesOut in 100 milliseconds. I can get my test pass if I use $timeout but I don't want to slow down the test runner waiting for the animation to complete. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324043/how-do-i-fake-time-a-jquery-animation-using-sinon-in-a-jasmine-unit-test) SO which describes how to 'turn off' jquery fx in a jasmine test but how do I inject the jQuery variable into my test?

Here is the directive function code snippet:

```
if(curtain.length > 0) {
  curtain.fadeOut(100, function (){
    curtain.remove();
  });
}
```

Here is my functioning test with $timeout:

```
it('should remove the overlay (curtain) from the page', function (){
  var config = {
    start: false,
    steps: []
  };

  //Initialize 
  var cmf = factory.getInstance(config);

  //add curtain
  cmf.curtain();
  var curtain1 = angular.element('body').find('#ng-curtain');
  expect(curtain1.length).toBe(1);

  //remove curtain
  cmf.curtain(true);
  var curtain2 = angular.element('body').find('#ng-curtain');
  $timeout(function (){
    expect(curtain2.length).toBe(0);
  }, 110);
});
```

Comment: I guess you do not have to inject it. It will be in the global scope if you have included the jquery script along with jasmine. In your original code were you injecting jquery?

Comment: Well jQuery's functions are available when using angular.element(selector), but if I try to log value of jQuery it is undefined.

Comment: Have you included jquery script along with jasmine scripts..?

Comment: I'm sorry jQuery is defined, but I could not run my spec when using jQuery variable due to jshint. However I found the solution: use the /* global jQuery */ flag for jshint to know that jQuery is in global scope and then jQuery.fx.off = true; is working as expected. Thanks for your help with this PSL